# As3 performance for Sprite beginFillBitmap vs addChild(bitmap)

Tags: actionscript-3

Just a quick question:

which of the following method of create a sprite have quick rendering and less memory usage?

Add bitmap to the sprite

```
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
sprite.addChild(bitmap);
```

vs

Draw rectangle and fill with bitmapData

```
var bitmapData:Bitmapdata = new BitmapData(100, 100);
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
sprite.graphic.drawRec(0, 0, 100, 100);
sprite.graphic.beginFillBitmap(bitmapData:Bitmapdata);
sprite.graphic.endFill();
```

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is faster because vector rendering mathematics are required to fill your shape in the latter.

If you want noticeable (and I mean very noticeable) performance gains, you should have *one* Bitmap on the stage. What you do from there is store references to `BitmapData` to represent graphics, and sample those onto your one Bitmap via [`.copyPixels()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29).

Example:

```
// This is the only actual DisplayObject that will hit the Stage.
var canvas:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
canvas.bitmapData = new BitmapData(500, 400);
addChild(canvas);


// Create some BitmapData and draw it to the canvas.
var rect:BitmapData = new BitmapData(40, 40, false, 0xFF0000);
canvas.bitmapData.copyPixels(rect, rect.rect, new Point(20, 20));
```

Comment: so copyPixeld will copy the bitmapData from rect and place on top of the cavnas bitmap, if i am correct? Thanks Marty, u always so helpful

Comment: @bluebill1049 Yep that's correct, and it can do that extremely quickly. It can do this 2000+ times per frame pretty comfortably. The only issue with this is you can't have rotation.